# How to create the feathered design of scrollview as given in image in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, scrollview

**Please first refer to image shown here**[image: reference image]
I am creating a scrollView in Android studio. I want that the top side has feathered effect so that when something scroll below it than it wouldn't have sharp hide .

Please help me in completing the project

I had default scrollview code so I am not providing any code here. I searched a lot on web but did not get any result